# ogrinfo: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name

Tags: django, postgis

```
ogrinfo: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name
```

I am getting above error on parsing shape file ESRI. I need do develop django project with PostGIS and i am trapped here. How do i get rig of it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try building SQLite from source with

```
CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA=1" ./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Reference - https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_column_metadata