# Geodjango Exception when importing django.contrib.gis.gdal: OSError: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name

Tags: postgresql, postgis, conda, geodjango

I have followed the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/gis/install/#spatial-database) for installing Geodjango on my Ubuntu 14.04. I am using Django 1.10 and Python 3.5, postgres-9.6 and postgis 2.3.

I have checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35123306/ogrinfo-symbol-lookup-error-usr-local-lib-libgdal-so-1-undefined-symbol-sql) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21513980/attributeerror-usr-lib-ogdi-libgdal-so-undefined-symbol-gdalversioninfo), but found no solution.
In a newly installed ubuntu 14.04 Virtual Machine, it worked.

But in my installation, when I tried making migrations, I got:
OSError: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name

Investigating a bit further, I tried simply:

```
from django.contrib.gis import gdal
```

And got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   
File "/home/pv/anaconda3/envs/dj110py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver  # NOQA   
File "/home/pv/anaconda3/envs/dj110py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/driver.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi, raster as rcapi   
File "/home/pv/anaconda3/envs/dj110py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/prototypes/ds.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import GDAL_VERSION, lgdal   
File "/home/pv/anaconda3/envs/dj110py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/libgdal.py", line 48, in <module>
    lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)   
File "/home/pv/anaconda3/envs/dj110py35/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 347, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name
```

Is there any suggestions on how I could repair my setup?

## UPDATE

It seems to be a problema with my conda environment. When I started using a pip virtualenv, the problem did not arise anymore. I am not answering the question, because I could not find the solution, only a workaround. But **rebuilding the environment with pip virtualenv works**.

Answer (score 4):

In conda environment: `conda install -c conda-forge gdal=2.2.1`

In django settings.py: 
`GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = '<HOME>/anaconda3/envs/<env_name>/lib/libgdal.so'`

Comment: When I run the command I got an error:

Fetching package metadata .............

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:
            
  - gdal 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue as well and the specifying

```
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = <HOME>/anaconda3/envs/<env_name>/lib/libgdal.so
```

(in `project.settings` or `os.environ.setdefault`) led to

```
libicui18n.so.56: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

The fix that worked for me was to upgrade icu:

```
conda install -c conda-forge icu=58
```

Upgrading icu lead to some changes in other package versions as well (qt downgraded from `5.6.2-4` to `5.6.2-3`, the rest upgraded).

Answer (score 0):

I simply run under my conda environment:

```
conda install gdal
```

[Guy de Carufel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44962760/4810382) did not work for me, though he pointed to a correct direction, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you built SQLite from source? Then, you forgot to enable Column metadata. Recompile SQLite with

```
CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA=1" ./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Have fun using the cutting edge SQLite.

Reference - https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_column_metadata