# OSError: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

I have followed the tutorial for installing Geodjango on my Ubuntu. I am using Django 1.11.2 and Python 2.7.6, postgres-9.3.2 and postgis 2.0.3.

I have checked here and here, but found no solution.

But after my installation, when I tried to run, I got error: OSError: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name

```
lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
```

Comment: Have you [installed SpatiaLite](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/install/spatialite/#installing-spatialite)?

Comment: This is most probably a configuration problem caused by duplicate installations of libgdal or sqlite from virtualenv/anaconda/postgis/system-wide python.  Try running `sudo updatedb` and then `locate libgdal.so` to understand what is in conflict, and delete unneeded copies.

Comment: Check this answer, if it is still relevant for you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54328577/4810382

Answer (score 3):

Try building SQLite from source with

```
CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA=1" ./configure
make
sudo make install
```

I use cutting edge SQLite, built from source, I've faced a similar situation and searched for an answer but nobody answered. Finally, this solved the problem.

Reference - https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_column_metadata

Answer (score -1):

### special thanks > more indifferent

### https://blog.csdn.net/qq_38979769/article/details/129723825

### download sqlite-autoconf-${current_version}.tar.gz version no amalgamation

```
tar -xvf sqlite-autoconf-3420000.tar.gz

cd sqlite-autoconf-3420000/

gedit sqlite3.c
```

### edit first macro definitions lines and add define SQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA 1 like this

```
#ifndef SQLITE_TCLAPI
#  define SQLITE_TCLAPI
#  define SQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA 1
#endif
```

### save and make install

```
./configure

make

make uninstall

make install
```

### enjoy

### if the installation is corrupted retry

`sudo apt install qgis qgis-plugin-grass`